# MSBuild - Get a list of projects by a condition

Tags: msbuild

I have the following MSBuild task which runs the "CustomBuildTask" task for every referenced project in parallel:

```
<Target Name="CustomBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <CustomProjectReferences Include="@(ProjectReference)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <MSBuild
      Targets="CustomBuildTask"
      BuildInParallel="$(BuildInParallel)"
      Projects="@(CustomProjectReferences)"
      Condition="'@(CustomProjectReferences)' != ''"
      ContinueOnError="true">
    </MSBuild>
</Target>
```

This seems to work fine. However is there a way I can improve this by filtering "CustomProjectReferences" on some condition. For example only select the projects which have the "CustomBuildTask" task defined or only select the ones with some property defined.

I'd appreciate the help as I'm looking to improve my build time. Thanks

Comment: You can only know what a project contains by evaluating it, i.e. Import or run it via MSBuild task. So here you'd have to first import the project then conditionally build it, so best case is you evaluate it once worst case is you evaluate it twice and call a target (which is definitely worse than what you have now). Pretty much impossible to answer if hat is going to improve build times without measuring: it probably depends on the number of projects and the number of those which actually need building.

Comment: @nfplee it's hard to tell where your build time comes from - if you have high evaluation times, then nothing can really help here since the project would need to be evaluated anyhow (either because of a prop check or calling a target). VS 15.5 is going to add a way to use `<MSBuild>` while ignoring projects that don't have a target (it just doesn't generate an error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @stijn points out in his comment, the project files represented by the `ProjectReference` items would each have to be evaluated by MSBuild in order to know all of the targets and properties defined therein. This would likely not be worth the performance expense. However, you may be able to get the data you need without a huge performance hit by using the [XmlPeek task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598684.aspx). Depending on your needs, this might be sufficiently reliable for the scenario you suggest where you are checking for the presence a target, but only if that target would never be incorporated via an `Import` nor ever have a `Condition` attribute. The property scenario would be much more dicey, only working if you know the property will never be defined via an `Import`, never defined or updated inside a `Target`, and never have a `Condition` attribute. If you go down this road, a helpful piece of the puzzle will be [Item Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-functions), e.g. `WithMetadataValue`.